# Scala 3 - generic programming with Product

Tags: scala, scala-3

According to https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/02/26/tuples-bring-generic-programming-to-scala-3.html

I can write correctly:

```scala
def tupleToCsv[A <: Tuple : RowEncoder](tuple: A): List[String] = summon[RowEncoder[A]].encodeRow(tuple)

case class Employee(name: String, number: Int, manager: Boolean)

val t = Tuple.fromProductTyped(Employee("Bob", 42, false))
println(tupleToCsv(t)) // List(Bob, 42, false)
```

but I'd like write a unique method `toCsv`

```scala
   def toCsv[A <: Product](t: A)(using m: scala.deriving.Mirror.ProductOf[A]):  List[String] = {
      val tuple = Tuple.fromProductTyped(t)
      val aa = summon[RowEncoder[A]] // ***
      aa.encodeRow(tuple)
    }
```

and call it with `toCsv(Employee("Bob", 42, false))`

the compiler at row *** says:

```
no implicit argument of type RowEncoder[A] was found for parameter x of method summon in object Predef
where:    A is a type in method toCsv with bounds <: Product
      val aa = summon[RowEncoder[A]]
```

how can I provide automatic derivation for A ?

Comment: I think *** row should be `val aa = summon[RowEncoder[m.MirroredElemTypes]]`

Comment: @Taha no, same problem

Comment: I may be missing something but why not define it as: `toCsv[A <: Product : RowEncoder]`?

Comment: @GaëlJ there isn't RowEncoder on A

Comment: Why do you thing that `A <: Product` will have a `RowEncoder` (as `A` is clearly not a `Tuple` ) ? Also, why do you think that once you have a `RowEncoder[A]`, you will be able to use it to encode a `Tuple` which you get from `Tuple.fromProductTyped(t)` (it will be a `RowEncoder` for `A`, not for a `Tuple`) ?

Comment: try change the method signature to `def toCsv[A <: Product](t: A)(using m: scala.deriving.Mirror.ProductOf[A], e: RowEncoder[m.MirroredElemTypes]):  List[String] ` and change `val aa = summon[RowEncoder[A]]` to `val aa = e`

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
def toCsv[A <: Product](t: A)(using m: scala.deriving.Mirror.ProductOf[A], e: RowEncoder[m.MirroredElemTypes]): List[String] =
    e.encodeRow(Tuple.fromProductTyped(t))
```